# BadPaddingException: Given final block not properly padded

Tags: java, iphone, aes

I want to send the encrypted data from iPhone to server(java).But the server is throwing the below exception.The stack trace is :

```
    javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Given final block not properly padded
at com.sun.crypto.provider.SunJCE_f.b(DashoA13*..)
at com.sun.crypto.provider.SunJCE_f.b(DashoA13*..)
at com.sun.crypto.provider.AESCipher.engineDoFinal(DashoA13*..)
at javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(DashoA13*..)
at com.justshare.util.Util.getDecryptedString(Util.java:59)
at com.justshare.util.Util.getRequestString(Util.java:226)
at com.justshare.servlets.MobileRegistration.processRequest(MobileRegistration.java:63)
at com.justshare.servlets.MobileRegistration.doPost(MobileRegistration.java:53)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:128)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:286)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:845)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:583)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:447)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Am using AES algorithm for encryption and my iPhone code is :

```
    - (NSData *)AES128EncryptWithKey:(NSString *)key{

char keyPtr[kCCKeySizeAES128 + 1]; // room for terminator (unused)
bzero( keyPtr, sizeof( keyPtr ) ); // fill with zeroes (for padding)

// fetch key data
[key getCString:keyPtr maxLength:sizeof( keyPtr ) encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSUInteger dataLength = [self length];

//See the doc: For block ciphers, the output size will always be less than or 
//equal to the input size plus the size of one block.
//That's why we need to add the size of one block here
size_t bufferSize = dataLength + kCCBlockSizeAES128;
void *buffer = malloc( bufferSize );

size_t numBytesEncrypted = 0;
CCCryptorStatus cryptStatus = CCCrypt( kCCEncrypt, kCCAlgorithmAES128,kCCOptionECBMode,
                                      keyPtr, kCCKeySizeAES128,
                                      NULL /* initialization vector (optional) */,
                                      [self bytes], dataLength, /* input */
                                      buffer, bufferSize, /* output */
                                      &numBytesEncrypted );
if( cryptStatus == kCCSuccess )
{
    //the returned NSData takes ownership of the buffer and will free it on deallocation
    return [NSData dataWithBytesNoCopy:buffer length:numBytesEncrypted];
}

free( buffer ); //free the buffer
return nil;
```

}

And the server side code for decryption is :

```
    public static byte[] key_reg = new byte[] {1, 2, 3, 4, 5,6, 7, 8, 9, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7};//... secret sequence of bytes

    public static String getDecryptedString(byte[] data,int i){
    String str = null;
    try {
        Cipher ci = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding","SunJCE");
        SecretKeySpec sk =   new SecretKeySpec(key_reg, "AES");
        ci.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, sk);
        byte[] dataD = ci.doFinal(data);
        str = new String(dataD,"UTF-8");
        return str;
    } catch (Throwable e) {
        logger.error("Error in getRequestString : "+e);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return str;
}
```

Comment: Does this question/answer help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4146324/javax-crypto-badpaddingexception-error ?